Definition of isomorphism of locally ringed spaces
A locally ringed space is a pair $(X,F)$ where $X$ is a topological space and $F$ is a sheaf of rings on $X$, such that the stalk $F_x$ is a local ring at every $x\in X$.
A map $(f,f^\#):(X,F)\to (Y,G)$ of locally ringed spaces is a pair where $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map and $f^\#:G\to f_*F$ is a sheaf morphism, such that the following homomorphism (that we call $f^\#_x$) is local for any $x\in X$:
$$G_{f(x)}\to (f_*F)_{f(x)}\to F_x.$$
Then I read that an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces is an invertible morphism, or equivalently a pair $(f,f^\#)$ with $f$ homeomorphism and $f^\#$ a sheaf isomorphism. But how come we are sure that $f^\#$ isomorphism guarantees that $f^\#_x$ is local? Of course $f^\#_{f(x)}$ will be local, since a sheaf isomorphism induces an isomorphism on the stalks, but I don't see at all how to prove that the canonical homomorphism $(f_*F)_{f(x)}\to F_x$ is local.

Are you sure it is not just assumed by definition to be local?

This follows from the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism. It namely holds that the canonical map $\mathrm{colim}_{f(x)\subset V\,\mathrm{open}}\,F(f^{-1}(V))\to\mathrm{colim}_{x\in U\,\mathrm{open}}\,F(U)$ is an isomorphism, since $f$ is a homeomorphism: the bijective assignment $\{\mathrm{open\,subsets\,of}\,Y\}\to\{\mathrm{open\,subsets\,of}\,X\}, V\mapsto f^{-1}(V)$ determines an isomorphism between the two poset categories $\{V\subseteq Y\,\mathrm{open}\mid f(x)\in V\}$ and $\{U\subseteq X\,\mathrm{open}\mid x\in U\}$. As such, the colimits over these categories that we are considering agree.
